# jQuery .hide('clip') effect causing a repeat effect when I click an image

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, overlay, show-hide

When I click my contact us nav link it opens smoothly and if I click anywhere in the overlay it closes smoothly, but it I click the close img, it has a studder while closing.

Also it closes if I click inside the "form-wrap", but obviously it needs to not do that so that so people can use that.

Here is a link and script.

http://jsfiddle.net/JohnWeb/fe5YZ/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav-contact, #foot-contact').click(function(){
        $('#overlay').show("clip", 600);
    });
    $('#close-btn, #overlay').click(function(){
        $('#overlay').hide("clip", 600);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the form closed when you click inside your form is because `#form-wrap` is wrapped inside `#overlay` div.

So the click event inside `#form-wrap` will trigger the click inside `#overlay` div as well.

You need to prevent it using **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**:

```
$('#form-wrap').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fe5YZ/1/)**

Comment: we've two different implementations for the same thing.

Comment: Shall I propose another one? `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @Luxelin No, you cannot use `event.preventDefault()` in this case, `event.preventDefault()` only prevent default action of the event, not prevent event bubble up the DOM tree

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't notice that the click event was on a parent element.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with the fact that the button element is a child of another element, which, when clicked, also causes the modal to be closed.

so, what you could do is:

```
$("#close-btn").click(function(e){
   $("#overlay").hide();
   return false;
}
```

This allows the button to work. If you want the form not to close the modal whenever you click somewhere, just add `$("#form-wrap").click(function(){event.preventDefault();})` to your script.